# SQL Server Copy Data With New Primary Key Without Removing Old Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

Say I have a `Name` table:

```
ID (PK) | ForeignKeyID (FK) | Data1 | Data2 |
```

Then say I have data such as

```
1 4 John 12
2 4 Josh 13
3 4 Kelly 15
```

Is there a way I can copy this data to the same table, changing just the primary and foreign keys?

Example:

```
4 99 John 12
5 99 Josh 13
6 99 Kelly 15
```

I have already created a new parent row (with id 99). In my table, I have set primary key to auto increment, so I don't care what my primary key values will be. Now, I want to grab all the rows where foreign key id = 4 and copy that data into this Name table where foreign key id = 99. I don't want to move the data. Data with foreign key = 4 should still be there.  How do I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to *duplicate* rows ?

Answer (score 1):

You need an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Name (ForeignKeyID, Data1, Data2)
SELECT 99, Data1, Data2
FROM Name
WHERE ForeignKeyID = 4
```